# Selecting cells with values from DEM those are above specific value corresponding to each polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, query, zonal-statistics

i have a shapefile with 2000 polygons and a DEM. i want to calculate zonal mean for each polygon considering values from DEM which are above a particular value for each polygon.

i want to it with ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: And where did you stuck?

Comment: i used 'Zonal Statistics as table' tool in arcgis 10.2. i want this tool to calculate mean for  only those cells having value greater then particular value (previously defined for each polygon). but this tool consider every pixel of DEM covered by particular polygon.

Comment: Convert polygons to raster using field where that thresholds value stored. Use raster calculator Con(orig>pgonsraster,orig) see if output is what you need for zonal statistics

Comment: That really worked. i got exactly what i wanted by using your method. you are really a genius.